# /dev/sda2: UNEXPACTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-repair, fsck

Hope all are doing well

I have a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop.

During the boot, I got the error as.. "**/dev/sda2: UNEXPACTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY** "

I guess some of the files on a disk get corrupted.
After exploring the few threads, I got to know that I need to repair the blocks using fsck utility

That's how I have applied the command **fsck -y /dev/sda2** in a halted terminal

Unfortunately, nothing happening.
I can't see any repair process, and a prompt is continuously blinking!

For reference, I have shared my laptop screen's photos

Can anyone help me here?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSoAe.jpg)
All suggestions and comments are welcome :)

Thanks,
Mahendra Sondagar

Comment: Thanks for redirecting.

The problem and error seem similar.

as I said, I'd already tried with the command fsck -y /dev/sda2.

But unfortunately, nothing is happening.

Cursor is continuously blinking.

how do I get to know that something is cooking?

Comment: Nothing is happening there, you may as well stop it. You need to boot into a live USB device, and then enter the command again.

Comment: The partition should **not** be in use for a file-system check to complete; thus was your provided `fsck -y /dev/sda2` command was done whilst sda2 was being used or not?  Why *live* media is usually used; it ensures the partition isn't in-use. Also the command (eg. `fsck`) is not the command for all file-systems, thus the command may differ depending on your *fs* choice.  Also note `fsck` performs LOGICAL CHECKS which cannot get past ACTUAL DISK ISSUES, your picture shows a IO error thus I'd check SMART health in *live* system **before** you attempted to logical/file-system checks.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: What you see on your screen is **not a command prompt**. You can type anything there, it will just be echoed. Try reboot to get a command prompt or use a livesystem. I guess your disk just broke.

Comment: Hi.. all.

i have tried with the live USB.

but I got the following errors msg.

e2fsck: Input/Output error while trying to open /dev/sda2

The superblock could not be read or could not describe a valid ext2/ext3ext4 filesystem 
if the device really contains an  ext2/ext3ext4 filesystem, then the superblock is corrupted, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternative superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or 
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>


After applying below two commands,

sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda2
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda2


I got the below error

Comment: sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda2
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda2

after using the above two commands, I got the error as follows

"e2fsck: bad magic number in superblock while trying to open /dev/sda2"